# Existe alguma forma multiplataforma de usar setas do teclado em c++?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cross-platform

Em windows tem a biblioteca conio.h. se eu não me engano é possível usar a setas do teclado no Linux usando o ncurses.h, mas eu queria uma solução mais multiplataforma onde o mesmo código fosse compilar em vários sistemas operacionais diferentes não tendo que mudar nada (Ou muita pouca coisa) pra funcionar.

Alguem sabe uma solução para meu problema ? Algo como uma função presente na biblioteca padrão do C++ ou um port do conio.h para Linux ou um port do ncurses para windows

Comment: Tanto quanto sei não existe nenhuma solução multiplataforma

Comment: Voce sabe se existe algo parecido nas bibliotecas QT ? Assim eu misturo as linguagens e dá tudo certo

Comment: Ou alguma biblioteca que não seja padrão mas seja multiplataforma ?

Comment: Multiplataforma não. Mas algumas frameworks já lidam com esses problemas tais como SDL, Allegro, Irrlicht entre outras